# Failed to download repository information(pidgin-developers ppa)

Tags: 11.10, software-center, update-manager, repository, pidgin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix a 404 Error using a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa)

Got this error when i tried to check for updates from my update manager,its showing me about some updates but gives me this error

W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.